# Why Apple partitions the SSD drive this way, and which partition should I removed?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, ssd, apfs

I am planning to reformat both of my drives in my 27 Inch iMac (mid 2011), and I have a question about the way the SSD is partitioned by Apple.

[image]

Why are there are three tiers in my SSD?

I don't want to accidentally erase any recovery partition and don’t see an explanation of these in the Apple Support website.

If I am to reformat the SSD drive, should I erase at the 'Mercury Electra' level?

Comment: It would help if you can add information such as model of Mac that you are using and if you have a Fusion drive.

Comment: It has to do with how APFS works. If you were to format a new disk as APFS, it would be automatically partitioned this way as well.

Comment: You say you are planning to reformat the hard drive (HDD), but the  'Mercury Electra' is a solid state drive (SSD). So, which drive are you going to reformat (erase)?

Comment: @DavidAnderson  Clarified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WDC WD100...` and the `Mercury Electra` are **devices**. They represent the physical drives that are attached to your Mac.

Devices contain one or more **volumes**. `Macintosh HD` is a volume on the WDC device. There will be other volumes on that device that aren't displayed.

The Mercury device uses Apple's new APFS format. This uses a structure called a **Container** to 'contain' the volumes. That's why there are 3 objects.

If you just want to wipe your existing volume of data, then erase `Macintosh SSD` and `Macintosh HD`. That will maintain any other existing volumes, such as Recovery partitions.